# "In the loop", what are the selection criteria for the working group users?

Tags: discussion, feedback, the-loop

> We’ll share regular updates about what we learn through our research, as well as ***create a new working group of users*** (made up of people from all corners of the developer community — from folks new to programming, those who don’t participate in Stack Overflow but are passionate about programming, experienced Stack Overflow users, frequent contributors, and more.) that we’ll lean on for regular feedback. This working group will be made up of a diverse group of folks. By the end of this year, ***we will have completed discovery for the working group of users and will have identified the people we would like to recruit***.<sup>1</sup>

My question is:

- What are the selection criteria? What are the profiles and how would you define them?

Ideally, I'd like to hear back from SO inc. but, of course, this question also targets our Community Users, and your opinion is important, your pros and cons about the selection criteria.

- How will SO inc. choose the panel of users?
- Will they need accessing some PII and asking for it?
- What about age/sex/culture/country/?...? and so on...

---

<sup>1. source: a digest of small pieces from the [stackoverflow blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/?cb=1)</sup>

---

This has been proposed as a possible duplicate of this one: [How does one join the new “working group”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339110/how-does-one-join-the-new-working-group). I don't think it's a duplicate, because my question asks for the criteria. IMO, it's one step ahead of the bullet-points listed in the other question, which focuses on the process.

What do I think of when talking about criteria? Well, ya'll seen some "draft" of the last survey. Will the points raised be part of the criteria? Some others? Which ones? How will SO inc. choose the panel of users? Accessing PII or asking for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one join the new "working group"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339110/how-does-one-join-the-new-working-group)

Comment: Also, it's not exactly clear what this working group will actually do. Will they gather feedback from the rest of the community? Will they be *identifiable* like mods are, or will they be anonymous?

Comment: There might be [some answers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339050/282094) but it's a fair distance from being a duplicate.