# What are the plans for the future usage of meta sites by the company?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, the-loop

Recently, it was announced that the meta sites would be decreased in their importance, in favor of other "communication loops" implemented by SO. I wrote a request to change that at [Please consider gathering Meta feedback before the "ship" stage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340164/294691). That was two months ago, in December '19.

However, I heard recently from a source inside the company (who I will not be naming or linking) that after the CEO's post on Meta.SO, [CEO's 2020 Kickoff Blog: Where do you see Stack Overflow going?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393155/4946380), a couple weeks ago, he discovered that he actually liked meta.

This is great news; if the CEO enjoys meta, then maybe he'll be active on it a bit (or at least browse) and get a feel for how things work from the perspective of the most engaged users of the site. But what does this mean for the planned other communication methods that were supposed to somewhat replace the function of meta? Are those going to be set aside in favor of meta? Implemented, but work in tandem with meta? Is the original plan still going forwards?

**What are the plans for meta and the other communication loops moving forwards?**

Comment: Who are you hoping will answer: Sara Chipps, the CEO himself or one of the Community Managers?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Any staff member would be fine. The answer should reflect corporate plans irrespective of who writes and posts it.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of: [Will Meta Stack Exchange be removed now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339051) and [What is the role of Meta after the arrival of “The Loop”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339149) But I'm pretty sure the first doesn't answer it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - My questions depends on newer information, and is asking because it is entirely possible that plans have changed. I don't think it's a duplicate of anything at the moment.

Comment: A question based on one insider's information. It's a bit of a weak premise. I mean, even if it were true that the CEO professes to like Meta, it doesn't mean that Meta's "role" is safe but I suppose that's where your question lies.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "*...it doesn't mean that Meta's "role" is safe.*" Indeed; that's why I'm asking the question. (And now a second source inside the company has stated that things look "hopeful" for meta.)

Comment: Related: *[Contact page provides weak guidance on providing feedback and making feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376986/contact-page-provides-weak-guidance-on-providing-feedback-and-making-feature-req#comment1256682_376986)*

Comment: Related: *[What a very bad day at work taught me about building Stack Overflow's community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow)*