# Improve or hide tooltip for original location in migration banner

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, migration, tooltips

When viewing a [migrated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339110/295232), a banner appears with a link to the revision list of the question at its original location. Hovering over it does not really provide new information: it's the title of the question as it appears in the URL:

[image]

This even leads to unreadable tooltips for Russian questions like [this one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1051928/223536):

[image]

The [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/295232) didn't get rid of this 'feature', see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59121699/4751173) (if your browser is in the test group):

[image]

Do you have any thoughts as to what would be useful information for this tooltip? The title isn't particularly useful as the current title is shown on the page already. If there are no good suggestions, I propose we get rid of the tooltip altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed this tooltip. It predates our non-English sites, and although I can hear how it *might* be useful, in this case it just seems to add confusion.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option, which I only thought of later, would be to use the tooltip to simply *describe what the link does*, e.g.

> view the history of the question at its original location

The system wouldn't even need to fetch additional information from the database for this.